# Can a 21 speed Shimano Tourney groupset get converted into a 7-speed?

Tags: shimano, gears, crankset, drivetrain, conversion

I currently ride a 3x7 Tourney bike, which I’ve upgraded moderately and it is riding nice. I’d like to know if I can somehow replace my 3-crankset for a simple one, and also get rid off the front shifter and its cable.

Comment: Whats your goal?  Added simplicity or lightness?  Can you ride around all the time everywhere you go with no need to change the front gear ?

Comment: Both, @Criggie. Most part of the time I'm using only 2 or 3 speeds in the bigger crank. It's good to know that I can use only a simple crank, however, I'm afraid to pass through chain alignment problems, I don't know if "the upgrade" is worthy.

Comment: Generally, 'upgrades' to Tourney level bikes are not worth it. You can end up spending a significant fraction of the purchase cost and have to solve annoying compatibility issues. However, if getting what you want is worth it to you, go for it.

Comment: That's my main concern, @ArgentiApparatus.

Comment: Not being rude, but if you're only using three gears then perhaps your technique could improve? Perhaps working on a higher cadence.

Comment: @Criggie, I usually spin out in those gears My usual or optimal cadence is around 90rpm, I suppose. I ride in the city, but my bike was originally a hardtail. Almost every gear in 2nd crank and below feels super slow or light, so I'd have to make my cadence insane. But I get your point, I guess. I love my hybrid, but I think sooner or later an upgrade for a roadier bike will come.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - note that some bikes will still need the front derailleur to help prevent the chain from falling off, which defeats the lightness goal, and only makes the bike slightly simpler.

You'd use the upper and lower limit screws to force the FD cage to an appropriate place, and then can remove the cable and shifter.

Comment: Instead of the front deraileur there are simple and light chainguides which can be used and mounted instead of the front deraileur. But that depends all on tracks that are ridden most. If it is pretty bumpy a chain guide is a must.

Comment: @criggie you Could mention if derailleur method is as good as chain guides or not. Certainly cheaper to use existing derailleur

Comment: @Swifty sadly I have no experience with that - being large, I need and love my triple chainrings.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah that's doable.

Best would be to get a crank which fit's the current bottom bracket where you can unscrew the chain rings. Then it's just a simple case of getting rid of the front deraileur and shifter and be good to go.

Comment: By your answer, I won't get any chain fall issues. Have you done this or can tell more about it?

Comment: Yeah I have done this on my girlfriends bike. Although with a 8-Speed rear mech. It's working fine on her city bike. But as said if you plan on riding rougher terrain you should think about an chainguide. Most likely I would test it and if your chain falls off often you can think about a chainguide or a Narrow/Wide Chainring. If you have to buy a new chainring I would recommend using one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.

Couple of options for single ring cranks:

If your current cranks have removable chainrings you can take off the outer and inner rings. You'll need short chainring bolts as the middle and outer rings typically share bolts, but these are available and inexpensive. You want to use the middle position for the single chainring as it aligns with the rear cassette the best. You can put the large ring in the middle position if you want.

A tourney equipped bike likely has a square taper axle bottom bracket. There are plenty of inexpensive single ring cranks available for this. Look for cranks for single speed bikes, or 'track' cranks.

Comment: I'd have to replace for a single ring crank, since my crankset is not removable.
Could I have some chainline alignment problems replacing the 3-piece crankset for a simple one?

Comment: Chainline problems are always a possibility when switching cranks. If you have square taper BB there are options as BB units with different length axles are available

Comment: As you can'r remove rings on your crank (I assume that's what you meant), easiest way forward is to get a upgraded triple crank that does have removable rings (probably very easy to find used and inexpensive on EBay).Triple crank will have correct chainline automatically.

Comment: BTW adding a pic of your crank will help us point out any potential problems

Comment: I see, however, if I get a triple crank, I should use the middle ring for the proper alignment, right? I never saw a middle ring with at least 48 teeth, but I'll take a look.

Comment: I'll love to illustrate the thread with pictures, but I'm at least 500 miles away from my bike right now. Will update ASAP

Comment: Big ring can be moved to middle position

Comment: That's good news. I don't really know how cranks and cranksets can be adjusted or aligned. Do you think there is any difference in stressing for a solution to 1x7 or 2x7?

Comment: On hybrids and MTBs 2x7 isn't a thing, 3 front rings are generally needed as there is a narrow spread of sprocket sizes in the rear. You could create a 2x7 by just ditching the smallest ring and adjusting limits on front derailleur. Chain line would be fine as long as you don't use big front - big rear (too often).